# Is it possible to get more advanced Ecmascript syntax highlighting for code snippets?

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I've done some searches and this doesn't appear to be an option as far as I can tell.

I know about `<!-- language: lang-js -->` and it works great, but it doesn't do a great job with some more modern Ecmascript and related frameworks like React, Angular, etc.

For example here's a React snippet from StackOverflow:

```js
const NavContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      categories: [],
      items: [],
      selectedCategory: null
    }
  },

  selectCategory(category) {
    this.setState({
      selectedCategory: category
    });
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.serverRequest = axios.all([
      axios.get(CATEGORIES_ENDPOINT),
      axios.get(PRODUCTS_ENDPOINT)
    ])
    .then(axios.spread((categoriesResponse, itemsResponse) => {
      console.log('Categories', categoriesResponse.data.data);
      console.log('Item', itemsResponse.data.data);

      // This `this` should work due to ES6 arrow functions
      this.setState({
        categories: categoriesResponse.data.data,
        items : itemsResponse.data.data
      });
    }));
  },
  // ...
});
```

And here's the same snippet inside my SublimeText:

[image: code example from SublimeText]

The differences are pretty stark.

I know web-based syntax highlighting is no match for a dedicated desktop app, but I guess my larger question is if there are more syntax highlighting options I don't know about or if there are ways to upgrade the options on StackOverflow in some way.

Comment: `if there are ways to upgrade the options on StackOverflow in some way.` Contribute to Google Code Prettify.

Comment: On the first part of your "larger question": [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109)

Comment: [This should do the trick](http://media.buzzle.com/media/images-en/gallery/quotes/450-quote-about-rainbow-glasses.jpg).

Comment: Joking aside, The sublime example is quite inconsistent. Why are some parens white, while others are blue? Why are both parameters, and that `null` orange? Why are `React` and `this` both red? Last, why would we need this. SO isn't a full IDE.

Comment: Looks like the blue parens are the ones which declare parameters, which are orange. `this` is a keyword, yet it's italic red, unlike `return` which is also a keyword. `React` is *not* a keyword though, and it's still red. `console` is yellow, while it's built-in it should be handled like any other object IMO. I'll have to agree with @Cerbrus that's it's too inconsistent.

Comment: Sublime formatting seems to be a complete mess. I far prefer the SO version. Although I would like a dark background. If you feel strongly about it you could always use greasemonkey.

Comment: Thanks for the info everyone. I know SO isn't Sublime but was just curious what options there were, if any.